# Appending to existing reports not working in extent report 4

Tags: extent

In extent report 4.0 and above how to append a new report to an existing report as I want to keep all the reports for today in one extent.html file. How to do that? Previously in extent report 3.0.1 `.setAppendExisting(true)` method was working.

Comment: Your question is addressed and answered on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237310/extent-reports-v4-overwriting-test-results)

Comment: hy Bill .Thanks for your help but in that context they are saying like "It is enhanced feature of v4. To overcome it, We have to use ExtentV3HtmlReporter class in version 4. " what does that means in coding i am unable to get. Again I have another issue as i run a test case my extent report is generating but when i run it again previous screenshots are missing from previous logs of the same extent.html file. Help plz.

Comment: The same issue I was getting, I was unable to do parallel execution in extent report 4.Also I tried .setAppendExisting(true) method was not yet working. Can anyone suggest me a solution in parallel execution of extent report 4.

Comment: I am not getting .setAppendExisting . I am using Extent report .netcore the latest version.

Comment: To use setAppendExisting( true) we need to downgrade the extent report version to 3. In v4 its under the paid one.